# rails username un url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

in Rails, I have a user model with :id and :name.
If I use

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show'
```

in  `config/route.rb`, with

```
http://app.com/1
```

I see the user, but if I use

```
match '/:name' => 'users#show'
```

don't work, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using generated controllers? The `show` action probably expects an `id` parameter (which is why it works). You need to use the correct ActiveRecord finder, such as  `User.find_by_name` if you want to pass in the `name` parameter.